# Los operandos para los operadores || y && deben ser convertibles a valores escalares lógicos error Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab me arroja este error `"Los operandos para los operadores || y && deben ser convertibles a valores escalares lógicos"`

X ES UN VECTOR CON VARIAS COLUMNAS, EL NUMERO REPRESENTA LA COLUMNA

CODIGO: **if x2 > 0 && x2 < 600 && x3 > 0 && x3 < 15000 && x4 > 0 && x4 < 15000**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lo posible trata de pegar código como texto y no como imagen, tu error no es reproducible ya que si yo me invento cualquier `x1`, `x2`, `x3` y `x4`, la expresión lógica funciona correctamente, ¿es posible  que alguna de estas variables no sea un escalar en tu código?.

Comment: Gracias, lo solucioné amigo. ¿Puedes revisar otra pregunta que acabo de hacer? es acerca de insertar varios datos a una base de datos desde matlab

Comment: Lo siento, no manejo sql, tal vez alguien más te pueda dar la mano, aunque creo deberías agregar más detalles, por ejemplo, el tipo de variables o que piensas hacer con la variable `query` creada, ¿alguien que sabe sql debería sobreentender eso?, si no, tal vez deberías agregar algún [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que quieres obtener.

Answer (score -1):

**LA SOLUCION ESTÁ EN CAMBIAR EL OPERADOR && POR &**